# How to get this jQuery in JavaScript to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of problems to convert a jQuery to a normal javascript. I'm a fresh programmer and it's pretty hard for me to get this to work.

I have to code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="msg[]" value="26" class="checkbox" />
<button type="submit" class="delete" disabled="disabled">Delete</button>

$(function() {
  $(".checkbox").click(function(){
    $('.delete').prop('disabled',$('input.checkbox:checked').length == 0);
  });
});
```

For Example you can try it here [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3U364/423/)

But how can I use this with javascript?

I can't get this code on Example site to run in my programm.

Comment: The code you've shown has only one checkbox, but the fiddle shows three. Please [edit] your question to explain what the code is supposed to do. (I think I can guess, but I shouldn't have to.)

Comment: I have updated the link. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume the intention is that the button should be disabled unless at least one checkbox is checked.

```js
// When the DOM is loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // bind a click handler to the checkboxes' parent element
  document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // when a click occurs test if the target element has the "checkbox" class
    if (e.target.classList.contains("checkbox")) {
      // if so, set the disabled state of the button
      document.querySelector(".delete").disabled = 
           // based on whether at least one checkbox is checked
           document.querySelectorAll("input.checkbox:checked").length === 0;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="msg[]" value="32" class="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" name="msg[]" value="44" class="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" name="msg[]" value="26" class="checkbox" />

<button type="submit" class="delete" disabled="disabled">Delete</button>
```

My code isn't directly equivalent to the jQuery because I've bound a single click handler to a parent element (in this case the `document`, but in your real page you should bind it to the nearest parent element of the checkboxes) instead of binding one to every checkbox, but otherwise it is pretty much the same thing.

Note that although all modern browsers support [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), IE < 10 does not. Also [the `DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) and [`addEventListener()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) aren't supported in IE < 9.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution

```
var checkboxElements = window.document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");
var deleteButtons = window.document.getElementsByClassName("delete");
var numberOfCheckboxesChecked = 0;

for(i =0; i < checkboxElements.length; i++)
{
  checkboxElements[i].onclick = checkboxClick;
}

function setDeleteButtonsState(){

  for(i =0; i < deleteButtons.length; i++)
  { 
    deleteButtons[i].disabled = numberOfCheckboxesChecked > 0 ? "" : "disabled";
  }

}

function checkboxClick()
{
  if(this.checked === true)
  {
    numberOfCheckboxesChecked++;
  }
  else
  {
    numberOfCheckboxesChecked--;
  }
  setDeleteButtonsState();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  var button = document.querySelector('.delete');
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach(function(checkbox){
    checkbox.addEventListener("change", function(e){
        button.disabled = document.querySelectorAll('input.checkbox:checked').length == 0;
    });
  });

}, false);
```